# nvd3 library: modify default position of LEGEND BOX THAT AUTOMATICALLY POPS UP WHEN YOU POSITION THE MOUSE IN THE CHART

Tags: javascript, charts, legend, nvd3.js, indicator

THIS IS NOT ABOUT THE NORMAL FIXED LEGEND.

I am using using nvd3 library for some charts and I need to modify the default position of the js legends that come up (on the bottom instead of on the right). I cannot find any documentation and tweaking the parameteres Ive seen in the code so far doesnt modify this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could tweak with the [ledgend.js](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/legend.js#L157), currently the legend position is set as far right as possible within the total width.

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate. The other question relates to the fixed legend on the top of the chart. My question is related to the box that automatically pops up when you position the mouse in the chart

Comment: The solution, if its on any help for anybody: on tooltip.js, look for left and top variables. Comment lines 211, 212 with 'left += chartContainer' etc. Modify these parameters according to your needs.